# Unwanted output for my Java code "if statement" (too long to describe in title)

Tags: java

Edit: added more code

(extremely new to java, and I don't have any textbooks. I am piecing together how it works from what I can find online, please be nice.)

I am trying to make a "time calculator" for my Java course in college. (It's our assignment). I have to make the output like so: (days) HH:MM:SS. If there are no Days, then it would be HH:MM:SS, and if no Hours, then it would be MM:SS, and so on.

However, in my code, my if statement for there being only seconds and no minutes or hours or days is not executing properly. If i enter 40 seconds, it will output: 0:00:40 hours. How do I fix this? I know there is a problem with the If/If else statements.

I have tried to figure out the problem by entering various numbers from 1-60, but it always returns as "0:00:(1-60) hours." I don't know where I'd begin to solve this problem.

```java
final int x = 9;
final int n_Days;
final int n_Hours;
final int n_Minutes;
final int n_Seconds;

n_Days = total_seconds / 86400;
n_Hours = (total_seconds % 86400 ) / 3600;
n_Minutes = ((total_seconds % 86400 ) % 3600 ) / 60;
n_Seconds = ((total_seconds % 86400 ) % 3600 ) % 60;

if (n_Days == 0) {

    if (n_Minutes < x || n_Seconds < x) {
    String padded = String.format("%02d" , n_Minutes);
    String padded2 = String.format("%02d" , n_Seconds);

    System.out.print("You entered " + total_seconds + " seconds, which is " + n_Hours + " hours, " + n_Minutes + " minutes, and " +  n_Seconds + " seconds.");
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print(n_Hours + ":" + padded + ":" + padded2 + " hours.");
    }
}
else if (n_Days == 0 && n_Hours == 0) {

    if (n_Minutes < x || n_Seconds < x) {
    String padded = String.format("%02d" , n_Minutes);
    String padded2 = String.format("%02d" , n_Seconds);

    System.out.print("You entered " + total_seconds + " seconds, which is " + n_Minutes + " minutes, and " +  n_Seconds + " seconds.");
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print(padded + ":" + padded2);
        }
}

else if (n_Days == 0 && n_Hours == 0 && n_Minutes == 0) {


    System.out.print("You entered " + total_seconds + " seconds, which is " +  n_Seconds + " seconds.");
    }

else {
    if (n_Minutes < x || n_Seconds < x) {
    String padded = String.format("%02d" , n_Minutes);
    String padded2 = String.format("%02d" , n_Seconds);

    System.out.print("You entered " + total_seconds + " seconds, which is " + n_Days + " days, " + n_Hours + " hours, " + padded + " minutes, and " + padded2 + " seconds.");
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print(n_Days + " days " + n_Hours + ":" + padded + ":" + padded2 + " hours.");
    }
}
```

If I input less than 60 as the total_seconds, then I want the 2nd "else-if" statement to execute like so:

"You entered 30 seconds, which is 30 seconds."

Comment: You might want to post more code, especially where you're setting the values for n_Days, n_Hours, etc. As far as your `if` statement goes, you're working from the general to the specific -- you want to do it the other way around. There are many cases where days = 0, but you deal with that as a first case, assuming that H, m and s are non-zero values when that might not be the case.

Comment: Not needed... problem is clear from what is posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (n_Days == 0)
```

This is your first `if`-statement. If `n_Days` is `0`, it will be executed and - most importantly - the `else`-statement never will. So if `n_Days` is `0` and `n_Hours` is `0` too, `if (n_Days == 0)` will be executed and the `else if...`-statements will just be skipped.

You just got to change the order of your statements - or nest them - and will be fine.